# Wordpress Front page Display Setting Missing

Tags: wordpress, admin, wordpress-4.6, wordpress-4.5

I have installed Wordpress 4.6/4.5/4.4 and  `Front page displays` option is missing from the `settings > Readings` section.

Any suggestions?

Note: no plugins are installed

[image]

Comment: Just checked 4.6.1 and it's there. Long shot, but maybe it's done by your theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned there are no plugin installed, there are two likely scenarios where this could happen. I'm assuming you have already tried switching to default WordPress themes.

1. You don't have any pages. I checked this one. WP hides that settings when there are no pages at all.
2. You chose X page as static front page and later that X page went to draft/deleted.

Comment: thanks man, it was the second one, i deleted the static page XD, i feel so stupid, thank you!...